# URLSession limits bandwidth use after multiple downloads on LTE and 5G

Tags: swift, xcode, networking, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I am using the `URLSession.shared.downloadTask(...)` to perform on average 1500-3000 downloads of small files to my device. The total size of the files after fully downloading are about 100MB

I have a method that logs my network speed after each download, and what I am noticing is that after about 200 or so downloads, my network speed drops tremendously by 90-95%

This only happens on LTE & 5G. After that, I'll run a speed test on my cellular network and it would be at my original speed.

Comment: Is your app in the foreground at the time?

Comment: Yes the app remains in the foreground the entire time